# Subgroups routing in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Can I have subgroups routing in Laravel 4 like this:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');

    Route::group(['before' => 'rootOnly'], function()
    {
       Route::get('/root', 'RootController@rootOnlyTask');
    }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve something like that?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that..but for route `/root` it will check for both before methods. Whenever you access `/root` it will first check if `admin` is true then it will go for `rootOnly`